# How to install Windows 8 next to Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, gparted, partitioning, boot-partition

I've installed Ubuntu and now I want to install Windows 8. I've already done restoring of grub from the terminal, but now I dont know what to do. What should I do to install Windows? Please tell me all the steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: UEFI with newer system or BIOS with older system. Post this to see current partition use. `sudo parted -l`. Then we can give better instructions or links to details for your type of install.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) -- Preceding is for BIOS/CSM/legacy; [Install Windows 7 with Ubuntu in GPT UEFI mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/434885/install-windows-7-with-ubuntu-in-gpt-uefi-mode) is for UEFI-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t have any issues, the issues occur when you have to dual boot an EXISTING Windows 8 OS and older Ubuntu versions. But if you are using 15.04 and you are installing Windows 8 after that there really should not be any issues or special procedures that you have to follow. You just may want to make a Ubuntu Livecd/flashdive and a [boot repair cd/usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to have as a failsafe to fix any booting issues after installs.